# Flex-Box как поставить внутри колонок айтемы в линию

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня есть блок в котором осуществляет дисплей по флексу - колонке. И проблема в том что последние три элемента мне нужно сделать в линию, но не получается. Никак не могу придумать решение для данной проблемы. Прошу помощи.

```
<div class="cart_main">
    <div id="item_product-{{item.product.slug}}" class="cart_item_product">
        <div>
            <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Изображение - {{product.image.name}}" width="120px" height="120px">
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'shop:product_show' product.slug %}">{{product.name}}</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
                <input type="number" class="update_cart" data-slug="{{product.slug}}" 
                value="{{item.quantity}}" min="1" max="8" onkeypress="return false">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="item_total_price-{{item.product.slug}}" class="product_price">
            <span>{{item.total_price}} &#8381;</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="del_from_cart" data-slug="{{item.product.slug}}">Удалить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.cart_main > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Для наглядности, вот эти элементы нужно поставить в линию */
.cart_main .cart_item_product div:nth-child(n+3) {
    flex-direction: row;  # как прописать грамотно?
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.cart_main>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart_main">
  <div id="item_product-{{item.product.slug}}" class="cart_item_product">
    <div>
      <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Изображение - {{product.image.name}}" width="120px" height="120px">
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="{% url 'shop:product_show' product.slug %}">{{product.name}}</a>
    </div>

    <div class='inner'>
      <div>
        <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
          <input type="number" class="update_cart" data-slug="{{product.slug}}" value="{{item.quantity}}" min="1" max="8" onkeypress="return false">
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="item_total_price-{{item.product.slug}}" class="product_price">
        <span>{{item.total_price}} &#8381;</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button class="del_from_cart" data-slug="{{item.product.slug}}">Удалить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Просто обернуть все `div`, начиная с 3, в другой `div`

Comment: спасибо большое!)